# Upper bound of the error of the interpolating polynomial

Tags: calculus, statistics, numerical-methods

Show the expression for the error of the interpolating polynomial:
$$f(x) − p(x) = (x − x_0) · · · (x − x_n) \frac{f^{(n+1)}(ξ_x)}{(n+1)!}$$

where $ξ_x \in [\min(x_0,...,x_n,x),\max(x_0,...,x_n,x)]$ imply the upper bound:
$$|f(x) − p(x)| \le |(x − x_0)| · · · |(x − x_n)| \frac{M}{(n+1)!}$$
where $M = \max_{y\in [\min(x_0,...,x_n,x),\max(x_0,...,x_n,x)]}|f^{(n+1)}(y)|$

So far, what I got is:

Proof:
$$f(x) − p(x) = (x − x_0) · · · (x − x_n) \frac{f^{(n+1)}(ξ_x)}{(n+1)!}$$
If we wanna bound it, first we have to take the absolute value of each term:
$$|f(x) − p(x)| = |(x − x_0) · · · (x − x_n)| \frac{|f^{(n+1)}(ξ_x)|}{|(n+1)!|}$$
Rearranging it:
$$|f(x) − p(x)| = |(x − x_0)| · · · |(x − x_n)| \frac{|f^{(n+1)}(ξ_x)|}{(n+1)!}$$
Now, in order to find the upper bound, we need to evaluate the function's derivative, so we bring an auxiliary variable, denoted as $y$, which traverses the entire domain of $ξ$. Then we calculate the maximum value of $|f^{(n+1)}(y)|$, which guarantees it's actually an upper bound, and thus we obtain the following expression:
$$|f(x) − p(x)| = |(x − x_0)| · · · |(x − x_n)| \frac{|f^{(n+1)}(ξ_x)|}{|(n+1)!|}  \le |(x − x_0)| · · · |(x − x_n)| \frac{M}{(n+1)!}$$
where $M = \max_{y\in [\min(x_0,...,x_n,x),\max(x_0,...,x_n,x)]}|f^{(n+1)}(y)|$

Is that actually the proof? I don't know if getting the $\max$ it's simple like that.